# How would I extract individual data from a column and use it to name a document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently on work placement from college, so my knowledge of javascript is limited, and my experience with spreadsheets and databases is even further limited, so I apologise if there is a very simple solution to this.

My Google Sheet acts as a database for an app that I am making at work.  There are multiple sheets in this database and each one it tailored to a specific location(siteID), ie, each cell in the siteID column contains the same name.

I am working on a script that takes the data from the sheet and applies t to  a template to create a google doc.  This part of the script is working.

Naming the template is fairly simple, as the siteID column contains the same data in each row, which means that I need only take the siteID from the first cell in the column.

This results in each document having the same name.

I want to use my tagNO. column to separate each new document. A tag number is a unique identifier for a machine stored in my database so that each document generated with the data from a particular will all have the same siteID followed by a unique tagNO.

As my script sits now, to name a document, I only need to take the data out of the very first cell in the siteID column, and the same thing goes for the tagNO. column.  I can either take the tagNO. from the first cell in this column, or from every cell in this column, resulting in the siteID and a long string of tag numbers.

So my question is, is there a method of individually taking a cell from my tagNO. column and applying it to a document, and then looking through the folder where these documents are stored to make sure that the next cell in the column does not already have a document linked to it.

This is what I am using to take the data from the first cell in the siteID col.

```
var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2,2,11,1).getValue();
```

I tried this method with the tagNo. col, but this resulted in the long string of tagNo. appearing on each generated document.

This is the entire script.

```
function onOpen(){
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Create Template", functionName: "createTemplate"}];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.addMenu("Template Generator", menuEntries);
}

function createTemplate(){
  var sleepInt = 1500;
  var templateId = "1uSAcH8F21zEjuprIcE2_d84ojQT24ek85Y1W6L17Xno"; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("starting");
  Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 18).getValues();
  ss.toast("created document and adding data");
  Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

  for(var i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    var body = doc.getActiveSection();
    body.replaceText("%SITEID%", row[0]);
    body.replaceText("%TAG%", row[1]);
    body.replaceText("%CATEGORY%", row[2]);
    body.replaceText("%DESCRIPTION%", row[3]);
    body.replaceText("%AREA%", row[4]);
    body.replaceText("%SERIALNO%", row[5]);
    body.replaceText("%MODEL%", row[6]);
    body.replaceText("%MANUAL%", row[7]);
    body.replaceText("%HOOKUP%", row[8]);
    body.replaceText("%WEB%", row[9]);
    //body.replaceText("Checks", row[10]);
    body.replaceText("%CONNECTED%", row[11]);
    body.replaceText("%CALIBRATED%", row[12]);
    body.replaceText("%AUTOMATED%", row[13]);
    body.replaceText("%SAT%", row[14]);
    body.replaceText("%SIGNED%", row[16]);

    doc.saveAndClose();

    ss.toast("added data");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16wRGBVdV0OZ5YfKhqEQSFMsux-ekGCCa");
    newFolder.addFile(file); 

    ss.toast("finished");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    //customise the title for document
    var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 1).getValue(); //this is grabbing the data in field B2
    var docTitleTag = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 12, 18).getValue();
    var name = doc.getName();
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
    doc.setName(docTitle + " " + docTitleTag + " " + today);

    ss.toast("Named the document");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt);

    var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16wRGBVdV0OZ5YfKhqEQSFMsux-ekGCCa");
    var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
    pdfFILE.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
    var theFolder = pdffolder;
    var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
    theFolder.addFile(theFile);

    ss.toast("Generated PDF");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepInt); 
  }
}
```

This is what I am using to name the document.
The second line of this is where my problem lies.
Currently this line is taking the first cell from the tagNO. col and applying it to every document the script creates.

```
var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2,2,11,1).getValue(); 
var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 3,11, 1).getValue();
var name = doc.getName();
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
doc.setName(docTitle + " " + today);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in how you're using `getRange` and `getValue` in this case, when using `getRange` the arguments are `getRange([row number],[column number],[number of rows],[number of columns])` which means you're grabbing 11 rows starting at row 2 in column 3 when you do `getRange(2, 3,11, 1)` which is all fine and dandy, however when you do `.getValue()` on that range, it is only going to return a single value from that range. This works for your `var docTitle` because all of your values there are the same and thus you don't notice that it's really only pulling one value.

What you can do for your desired effect of iterating through each ID is by using `.getValues()` which returns a Two-Dimensional array of values from the range. You can then use a `for` loop to iterate through this array to get each Tag Number every time the loop runs. In fact, since the code already lies inside a `for` loop (assuming it iterates the same number of times as rows you have in your Tag Number column) you likely won't have to use a separate for loop.

I would recommend first changing these two lines

```
var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2,2,11,1).getValue(); 
var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 3,11, 1).getValue();
```

to

```
var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2,2,11,1).getValues(); 
var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 3,11, 1).getValues();
```

and then moving that entire block (aside from `var name`) of variable declarations above the `for` loop so that the code runs faster (it won't have to do a `.getRange` or recalculate the date every time the loops iterates) like so

```
. . .
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 18).getValues();
ss.toast("created document and adding data");
Utilities.sleep(sleepInt)

var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2,2,11,1).getValues(); 
var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 3,11, 1).getValues();
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

for(var i in data){
  var row = data[i];
. . .
```

then finally down where you previously had those declarations you can place something similar to the following (using variable names that work for you of course, this is just an example)

```
var newDocTitle = docTitle[i][0];
var newDocTitleTagNumber = docTitleTagNumber[i][0];
```

This will use `i` to iterate through each row in the first (and in this case only) column, and if you change the other variable names below accordingly, will use those in the name for each new document you create.